# Get free axis on facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

From my example data below I am looking for a way to get free y-axis for both of the grids.
Any suggestions?

```
structure(list(value = c(146252.877777778, 144608.111111111, 
560917.218390805, 404036.908045977), Gene = c("COX2", "ND4", 
"miR-148a-3p", "miR-26a-5p"), variable = c("Mean", "Mean", "Mean", 
"Mean"), CumValue = c(146252.877777778, 290860.988888889, 560917.218390805, 
964954.126436782), CumPerc = c(0.0120534892126705, 0.0239714243249686, 
0.119139138815869, 0.204956809759403), Cumulative = c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), Group = c("Messenger RNA", "Messenger RNA", "MicroRNA", 
"MicroRNA")), row.names = c("COX2", "ND4", "hsa-miR-148a-3p", 
"hsa-miR-26a-5p"), class = "data.frame")



library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)

    mat.mean.mRNA.miRNA %>%
  group_by(CumPerc) %>%
  top_n(20) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Group = as.factor(Group),
         name = reorder_within(Gene, CumPerc,Group)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, CumPerc)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Group, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 8) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) +
  labs(y = "Cumulative percentage",
       x = NULL,
       title = "",
       subtitle = "")
```

Comment: scales = "free"?

Comment: You could use `scales = "free"` which gives you both x and y scales controlled by the maximum and minimum  x and y values. It would look better if you removed `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))`

Comment: That worked. I though I tried scales = "free".